# How to Calculating ROC and AUC in Caffe?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, caffe, roc

I have trained a binary-classes CNN in Caffe, and now i want to plot the ROC curve and calculate the AUC value. I have two quetions:
1) How to plot the ROC curve in Caffe with python?
2) How to calculate the AUC value of the ROC curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has [`roc_curve`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_curve) and [`roc_auc_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score) functions in `sklearn.metrics` module, just import and use them.

Assuming you have a binary prediction layer that outputs a two-vector of binary class probabilities (let's call it `"prob"`) then your code should look something like:

```
import caffe
from sklearn import metrics
# load the net with trained weights
net = caffe.Net('/path/to/deploy.prototxt', '/path/to/weights.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
y_score = []  
y_true = []
for i in xrange(N): # assuming you have N validation samples
    x_i = ... # get i-th validation sample
    y_true.append( y_i )  # y_i is 0 or 1 the TRUE label of x_i
    out = net.forward( data=x_i )  # get prediction for x_i
    y_score.append( out['prob'][1] ) # get score for "1" class
# once you have N y_score and y_true values
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label=1)
auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_true, y_scores)
```

Comment: I have solved it with the same method with yours, but thx for your answer anyway！